# Does a wolf animal companion become Large when it advances to 4 HD?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, animal-companions, creature-size

Let's say one of my player plays a druid. And let's assume they reached level 3.

The wolf gains 2 bonus HD, which brings it to 4. In the wolf entry in the MM, it says a 4+ HD wolf grows Large.

Does a druid's wolf animal companion grow larger?

Comment: [Related] [Animal companion: Wolf to Dire wolf](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60298)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do druid animal companions get ability points due to high HD?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/do-druid-animal-companions-get-ability-points-due-to-high-hd)

Comment: the question is not the same, however the answer is so well furnished that the answer applies as-is. 
it would be poor form to copy-paste without the original answerer's approval...

Comment: oh, thats new.... "That solved my problem!" button 
i want to know the Worth of keeping them separate, vs accepting the différences...
Because i would NEVER have found the answer because ability points was NOT what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

No, the bonus HD a druid grants his animal companions are not the same as regular HD gained through Advancement, so you do not trigger any of the regular Advancement features that trigger on reaching certain HD. Which mostly means the size increases.

Comment: So when it says, "An animal companion gains additional skill points and feats for bonus HD as normal for advancing a monster’s Hit Dice (see the *Monster Manual*)" (*PH* 36), that list is inclusive, and an animal companion *doesn't* gain anything *else* for bonus HD as normal for advancing a monster's Hit Dice? (I know you're correct, but I think *some* amount of textual evidence should be presented.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Additionally, that phrase challenges the conclusion that the wolf *doesn't* gain the size increase. I think citations are needed.